# How To know the Size of HTTPS or HTTP Packets except for Retransmission

Tags: http, tcp, wireshark

It's about HTTP(s)  or TCP protocol.

I am learning HTTP using Wireshark, I see lots of retransmission packets in TCP protocol. And I want to calculate the total size of data sent by client-end to server-end, except for retransmission.

How can I get the whole pure size of data I sent to server, except retransmission?

Is there any flag for retransmission in TCP protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "retransmission" flag it TCP. Finding retransmissions requires analyzing the sequence numbers of sent segments, which is something wireshark does - for instance, you can use the display filter `tcp.analysis.retransmission` to find TCP segments that wireshark considers to be retransmissions.

To find the amount of data sent in a tcp session, right click any segment from the session, and click `Follow` -> `TCP Stream`:

[image]

It'll generate a display filter such as `tcp.stream eq 138` and show you the entire content of the selected tcp session, including the amount of shared data, regardless of retransmissions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton ! I am a student, and I am interested in your answer. I want to ask you more quetions! I am now reading books about TCP Conversation. HTTP data will be transfered through different TCP segments, the sum size of these TCP segments minus each TCP header  is the pure http data size ? Actually, I am interested in HTTPS GET And POST, I want to distinguish whether the specific https communicate is by Get  or POST. Can you give me any advice, Thank you very much

Comment: 1. In a normal HTTP session, TCP's payload will be HTTP. So the payload size will be HTTP headers + data. 

2. I'm not sure I understand your second question about distinguishing GETs from POSTs. Perhaps you should ask it as a separate question and provide more detail into what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks,I know your mean. Please forgive me and allow me to ask you some extra quetions. As your picture shows,the entire conversation is 230kb. 1. A TCP conversation will transfer multiple HTTP packets data, is that right? 2. Please, for instance, I open browser,and surf https://github.com/, Are the whole HTTP packets in one single TCP conversation? 3.The sum size of the http data I sent to github is the size of client-to-server unidirectional TCP conversation?Thank you, Best Wishes.

Comment: A website consists of many objects such as images, scripts, text etc. When opening a website your browser will request all relevant assets using HTTP. It's up to the browser to decide how many TCP sessions to open for each website, and it depends on which version of HTTP is used (1.1 or 2)